# ConTct$HttpPost cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, post, request

I'm trying to make a POST request within class HttpPost extends AsyncTask implements HttpUriRequest.

When I am writting : `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));` It shows me error in compilation time saying :

```
The method setEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity) is undefined for the type 
     ConTct.HttpPost. It says that I should make casting like this : ((HttpResponse) httppost).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

In running time, it prints :"`ConTct$HttpPost cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpResponse`".

Please see bellow my code :

```
public class ConTct extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{

    Button mButton;
    EditText mFullName, mEmail, mDialZone, mPhone;
    static WebView mWebView;
    static ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EditText mBrokerId, mIP, mAreaPhonePrefix, mLastName, mPassWord, mCampaign, mSubCampaign, mCountryID, mCity, mAdress, mIsDemo;




    public static final String myURL = "http://iphoneapp.optionrally.com:5757";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.contct);

        mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitRegisterButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mFullName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        mEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        mDialZone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.countryPhonePrefix);
        mPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

        mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TheWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://media-dispatcher.com/tds/mobile/?mdaf=FormInApp");



        mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);


        GetCountryZipCode();

        setUpInvisibleFields();

        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
        ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(AppManager.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    }//oncreate()




    private static class TheWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



    }//MyWebViewClient






    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (GeneralValidation()==true){




            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for your registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThanksZuser.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();


                  //#HERE I AM SENDING THE DATA
                   grabURL(myURL);




        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "*Fill the form correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }//onclick()


    public boolean GeneralValidation(){
        boolean result = false;

        final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pass = mFullName.getText().toString();
        final String phone = mPhone.getText().toString();


        if(!isValidEmail(email) || !isValidFullName(pass) || !isValidPhoneNumber(phone)){

            if(!isValidEmail(email)){
                mEmail.setError("Invalid email");
                mEmail.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                mEmail.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            if(!isValidFullName(pass)){
                mFullName.setError("Invalid name. You have to input at least 3 characters");
                mFullName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                mFullName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            if(!isValidPhoneNumber(phone)){
                mPhone.setError("Not Valid Number");
                mPhone.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                mPhone.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

        }else{
            result=true;

        }
        return result;
    }//GeneralValidation

    // validating phone
    private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phone2) {

        boolean check;

        if(phone2.length() < 6 || phone2.length() > 13){
            check = false;
        }else{
            check = true;
        }
        return check;
    }


    // validating email 
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    // validating full name
    private boolean isValidFullName(String pass) {
        if (pass != null && pass.length() > 2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String GetCountryZipCode(){
        String CountryID="";
        String CountryZipCode="";

        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //getNetworkCountryIso
        CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
        String[] rl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
        for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
            String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
            if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
                CountryZipCode=g[0];
                break;  
            }
        }
        mDialZone.setText( "+ " + CountryZipCode);
        return CountryZipCode;
    }//GetCountryZipCode




        class HttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements HttpUriRequest{

            public HttpPost() {
                super();
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }



            public HttpPost(String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                BufferedReader inBuffer = null;
                String result = "fail";
                String url = myURL;

                // Create a new HttpClient 
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);


                String l_ID, l_BrokerId, l_IP, l_SubBrokerID, l_AreaPhonePrefix, l_additionalPrefix, l_LastName, l_PassWord, l_terms, l_isLead, l_skinId, l_Campaign, l_languageId, l_SubCampaign, l_CountryID, l_City, l_Adress, l_IsDemo, l_birthday;

                l_ID = "1010";
                l_BrokerId = "4";
                l_SubBrokerID="sub broker id";
                l_IP="127.0.0.1";
                l_AreaPhonePrefix= " my area phone prefix";
                l_LastName= "my last name";
                l_PassWord="my password";
                l_languageId="2";
                l_terms="on";
                l_Campaign="1824";
                l_SubCampaign="my sub campaign";
                l_additionalPrefix="my prefix";
                l_CountryID= "my country id";
                l_City = " my city";
                l_Adress= " my adress";
                l_IsDemo="NO";
                l_birthday="1900-01-01 00:00";
                l_isLead = "yes";
                l_skinId="my skin ID";


                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("<req>",""));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("id"), l_ID));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("brokerId"), l_BrokerId));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("subBrokerId"), l_SubBrokerID));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("<msg>"), ""));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("ip"), l_IP));      
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("password"), l_PassWord));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("countryId"), l_CountryID)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("campaign"), l_Campaign));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("languageId"), l_languageId)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("lastName"), l_LastName));  
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("additionalPrefix"), l_additionalPrefix));  
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("p"), l_birthday)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("birthday"), l_birthday));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("terms"), l_terms)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("subCampaign"), l_SubCampaign));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("isLead"), l_isLead));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("isDemo"), l_IsDemo)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("address"), l_Adress));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("city"), l_City)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("areaPhonePrefix"), l_AreaPhonePrefix));                
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("skinId"), l_skinId));


                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("mobilePrefix"), mDialZone.getText().toString())); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("mobileNumber"), mPhone.getText().toString())); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("firstName"), mFullName.getText().toString())); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PrepareXmlItemTag("email"), mEmail.getText().toString())); 

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("</msg>", ""));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("</req>", ""));

                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                     result="got it";
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     result = e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     result = e.getMessage();
                }finally{
                    if (inBuffer != null) {
                        try {
                            inBuffer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }


                return result;
            }




            @Override
            public RequestLine getRequestLine() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void addHeader(Header header) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsHeader(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Header[] getAllHeaders() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Header getFirstHeader(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Header[] getHeaders(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Header getLastHeader(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public HttpParams getParams() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public ProtocolVersion getProtocolVersion() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public HeaderIterator headerIterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public HeaderIterator headerIterator(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void removeHeader(Header header) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void removeHeaders(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void setHeader(Header header) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void setHeaders(Header[] headers) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void setParams(HttpParams params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void abort() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public String getMethod() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public URI getURI() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAborted() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

        }





        public void grabURL(String url){

            new HttpPost().execute(url);

            }

    private String PrepareXmlItemTag(String tag){
        return "<" + tag + ">" +  "</" + tag + ">";
    }




}//ConTct.class
```

Please please, help me with this one:)

Comment: change your asynctask class name from HttpPost to anything else. Httppost is predefined class used in apache package

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
```

use this line

```
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost httpPost = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost(url);
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is the different between them and why it's better to use your way?